# Sql Server create html tags

Tags: html, sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

I am generating html from stored procedure, But it encode html tags into '<', '>' or '&'. I require tags as I generate them. I have tried with [CDATA] but did not get the result I expected.

```
select '<ul class=''downloaditems-grid''>'+(
                select stuff(
                (
                    select  '<li>'+ convert(nvarchar(max),Filepath) +'</li>'
                        from(
                        select ('<p>'+UploadDocumentName+'</p><a target=''_blank'' class=''ml10'' href='''+DocumentFilePath+'''title=''Download''>') As Filepath from table1 CLRD 
                         where                      
                        isnull(CLRD.IsDeleted,0) <> 1   and orderid=2
                 ) 
             as T for xml path('')),1,2,'')) +' </ul>'   a
```

It returns

```
<ul class='downloaditems-grid'>t;li&gt;&lt;P&gt;bill.png&lt;/&gt;&lt;a target='_blank' class='ml10' href='2c0a7c0c-d228-4f5d-9a8f-eb32911509db.png'title='Download'&gt;&lt;/li&gt; </ul>
```

But my requirement is:

```
<ul class='downloaditems-grid'>
<li><p>bill.png</p>
<a target='_blank' class='ml10' href='2c0a7c0c-d228-4f5d-9a8f-eb32911509db.png' title='Download'>
</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Table structure

[image]

Can any one give some hints, other than use **replace** how i decode there while creating html tags?

Comment: what kind of server side language do you use to access sql server from html? Why don't you use that language to build the html?

Comment: I am using C#, But i am trying this in stored procedure. Yes i can do this thing in C# or in scripting language but want in sp(sql-server). How i prevent encode tag in html query?

Comment: You should **(almost) never** create XML by concatenating strings. You'll get into hell if your strings contain forbidden characters. You might trick around but you should - if ever possible - build the XML properly. And better use a scalar function than a stored procedure. This is much easier to query...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your "generated" XML is invalid in several points of view...

With SQL Server you can easily create valid **XHTML** like this:

```
SELECT 'downloaditems-grid' AS [@class]
      ,'bill.png' AS [li/p]
      ,'_blank' AS [li/a/@target]
      ,'ml10' AS [li/a/@class]
      ,'2c0a7c0c-d228-4f5d-9a8f-eb32911509db.png' AS [li/a/@href]
      ,'Download' AS [li/a/@title]
FOR XML PATH('ul')
```

The result (which seems to be quite similar to the one you tried

```
<ul class="downloaditems-grid">
  <li>
    <p>bill.png</p>
    <a target="_blank" class="ml10" href="2c0a7c0c-d228-4f5d-9a8f-eb32911509db.png" title="Download" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

And be aware a **HTML is dirty** and **absolutely not the same as XHTML**.

#### Short explanation:

In `XML` there is a sharp separation between the tags and attribute names and the content. Some characters are absolutely forbidden out of clear reasons (`<, > and &` and many special characters can lead to unexpected results in combination with the string encoding. Tags and attributes have clearly documented limitations. The content may be anything, but: **The content will ever need correct escaping, therefore your forbidden characters where transformed into xml entities**

`CDATA` won't help you as it is not supported by `FOR XML PATH` (although there is `EXPLICIT`...), anyway, `CDATA` would not solve your problem, even if it worked...

Your concatenated xml string was invalid in many points of view (e.g. `</>` or missing blank...)

### UPDATE use with table data

Here is the code to use this with table data. Be aware, that I added forbidden characters to line 3!

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(DocumentFilePath VARCHAR(100),UploadDocumentName VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('File1.png','This is file 1')
,('File2.png','This is file 2')
,('File&3.png','This is file 3& with forbidden <>!!')

SELECT 'downloaditems-grid' AS [@class]
      ,(
        SELECT
           'bill.png' AS [p]
          ,'_blank' AS [a/@target]
          ,'ml10' AS [a/@class]
          ,tbl.DocumentFilePath AS [a/@href]
          ,tbl.UploadDocumentName AS [a/@title]
      FROM @tbl AS tbl
      FOR XML PATH('li'),TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('ul')
```

This is the result

```
<ul class="downloaditems-grid">
  <li>
    <p>bill.png</p>
    <a target="_blank" class="ml10" href="File1.png" title="This is file 1" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>bill.png</p>
    <a target="_blank" class="ml10" href="File2.png" title="This is file 2" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <p>bill.png</p>
    <a target="_blank" class="ml10" href="File&amp;3.png" title="This is file 3&amp; with forbidden &lt;&gt;!!" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Definitely investigate `FOR XML` -- it does all the escaping for you and SQL server just doesn't have the power with string manipulation to do it right. There's no value in hand-rolling your own attempt at escaping characters. IIRC there are differences in HTML and XML escaping (maybe apostrophes?) which can be evil...

Comment: @SteveCooper Is this really a comment to my answer?

Comment: @Shnugo My table have multiple results( multiple <li>). at that time how i can manage this with xhtml

Comment: Yes, I am going to :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi and your code use this :

```
replace( replace( @body, '&lt;', '<' ), '&gt;', '>' )
```

Comment: Yes, This is method to replace these ones, but i am trying to find another solution. This fails when a query returns multiple html encoded chars.  then how many time we will use replace keyword.

Answer (score 1):

First, your markup is wrong. It should be `'<P>'+UploadDocumentName+'</P><a target=''_blank'' class=''ml10'' href='''+DocumentFilePath+''' title=''Download''/>'`
Use regular XML building features

```
    select        
       [ul/@class]='downloaditems-grid',
       [ul]=(
       select [P]=UploadDocumentName,
                [a/@target]='_blank',
                [a/@class] ='ml10',
                [a/@href]=DocumentFilePath,
                [a/@title]='Download' 
       from ( 
              -- sample data
              values
               ('123','ad/df')
              ,('456','xx/yy')
            ) CLRD (UploadDocumentName, DocumentFilePath)
       for xml path('li'), type
       )
for xml path('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation for creating a HTML option input using the values from a database table.

````
SELECT 'output', '<div class="form-group">' + (
 SELECT       
       [select/@class]='form-control m-bot15',
       [select/@cntrl]='Sample',
       [select]=(
       SELECT` 
            [option/@value] = column_id, 
            [option]= column_description
       FROM 
              -- data from database table
                Table_Name
            
       FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
       )
FOR XML PATH('') 
  ) + '</div>' ```
````